# What's the supremum of $\{x \in F: -2 < x \le 2\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, real-numbers

The answer in my book defines one of the variables in terms of $\max$ function which seems to cause some sort of weird inconsistency. Instead I rewrote the proof as that below. I am asking if that makes sense. Thanks.

Let $T = \{x \in F: -2 < x \le 2\}$.

By definition, $2$ is an upper bound of $T$.

Let $-2< B < 2$ and $z = \frac 12(B + 2)$.

Then $z = \frac 12(B + 2) < \frac 124 = 2.$ But $z > -z > -2$. Thus $z \in T.$

$z - B = \frac{B + 2}{2} - B = \frac{B + 2 - 2B}{2} = \frac{2 - B}{2} = 1 - \frac{B}{2} > 0$ because $B < 2 \iff\frac B2 < 1 \iff 0 < 1 - \frac B2$. Then $z > B$. Thus $B$ is not an upper bound implying $\sup(T) = 2.$

Comment: Of course, if $\max S$ exists for a set $S$, then $\max S = \sup S$. The concept of supremum generalizes that of maximum.

Comment: What is $F$? What is $F$

Comment: $F$ is a field. In my book they define $z = \max \{0, \frac12(B + 2)\}$. Since $-2 < B < 2, \ \frac12(B + 2) > 0$ for any $B$, so I don't see what the point of $\max$ is.

Comment: Then it makes no sense.  How would you make sense of this in, say, $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$?

Comment: In that case we could restrict $F$ to $F = \mathbb R$.